# Function to stretch/compress audio files to have a preset number of samples in python?

Tags: python, audio, compression, signals, sampling

Basically I have a number of wav files of different lengths but the same sampling rate and thus of different number of samples, and I want them all to have the same number of samples, n_samp. This seems like it would involve speeding up or slowing down files to conform to n_samp. Is there a prebuilt function/library for doing this in python? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow changing the pitch, you could just interpolate the wav files to be changed by [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html). If you want to keep the pitch, you could use [Paulstretch](https://github.com/paulnasca/paulstretch_python), which -- as far as I see -- implements a kind of [SOLA-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_time-scale/pitch_modification#SOLA) for time stretching.